# why read a reference counter value as a reference-to-a-volatile-constant?

Tags: c++, boost

In the Boost 1.5.1 source under `smart_ptr\detail\atomic_count_win32.hpp` is a neat little atomic reference counter `boost::detail::atomic_count`.

on line 48, they do a cast I'm curious about:

```
class atomic_count
{
public:

// ...

operator long() const
{
    return static_cast<long const volatile &>( value_ );
}

private:
long value_;
```

Why is the counter value cast to a-reference-to-a-volatile-constant-long (`long const volatile&`)?

Comment: What is the type of `value_`?

Comment: @slavik262: It's a regular (non-CV-qualified) `long`.

Comment: what strike me more are the [earlier versions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/boost/detail/atomic_count_win32.hpp)

Comment: @Paul in general for this kind of things put a link to the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC provides a now-deprecated [*extension* on `volatile` variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), giving them acquire and release semantics (memory ordering guarantees, with respect to multithreaded programming.)

This cast "enables" this extension on the variable, giving it read-acquire semantics (to match any release-writes that may also occur). Again, this is, *non-standard*. In C++11 code you should use `std::atomic<>`.

They need this because `boost::shared_ptr` gives guarantees of correctness for `shared_ptr<T>` in multithreaded (shared) use; this is their implementation of a [lock-free](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming) counter.

(Also, this is only half the story: while this extension may provide the needed ordering and visibility guarantees, it does not guarantee atomicity. On Win32 this is guaranteed implicitly by the platforms it runs on: aligned word-sized integer reads and writes are atomic per the platform.)

To nip it in the bud before it starts: without this extension `volatile` is not useful for multithreaded programming. Don't even try. This extension is deprecated, so you should really avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

On x86 platforms, for aligned values of native width, this is known to be sufficient.

The problem they're trying to avoid is this:

1. The variable has the hex value `0000FFFF`.
2. Thread A starts to read the value and gets the `0000xxxx` part.
3. Thread B increments the value from `0000FFFF` to `00010000`.
4. Thread A finishes reading the value, getting the `xxxx0000` part that it hadn't read yet.
5. Thread A has now read a value of `00000000`!

This is called word tearing. However, it is known that this doesn't happen for aligned types of native width on x86. So a mere cast through `volatile` (which is known to avoid problematic compiler optimizations) is all that is needed.

Note that this is not some general truth. This just happens to be a property of the platform. This isn't portable code.

Comment: i have to admit one thing dave, I dont understand "sufficient."

Comment: I mean that it is known that nothing more aggressive (such as inline assembly or a compiler intrinsic) is needed. (I updated the answer with some details.)

Comment: Atomicity is only half the requirements, you also need to address ordering and visibility. For that you either need implicit guarantees from the platform (like x86 being a strongly-ordered platform) or memory fences, which MSVC provides on `volatile` as an extension, hence the cast. By the way, your answer is confusing (which UmNyobe is alluding to) because you say "sufficient" and "all that is needed" without ever stating the goal ("atomicity").